# How to loop through all SubFolders and get contents of Row 1 of each Excel file?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out a way to open all Excel files in all SubFolders, and get the all values from all cells in Row 1 and all formats for all these cells.  I think my code below is pretty close, but I think one of the references is incorrect, or something like that.  Anyway, when I run the code, it opens the first Excel file, and about a second later everything freezes up.

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

Range("A:L").ClearContents
Range("A1").Value = "Name"
Range("B1").Value = "Path"

Dim strPath As String
strPath = GetFolder

Dim OBJ As Object, Folder As Object, File As Object

Set OBJ = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = OBJ.GetFolder(strPath)

Call ListFiles(Folder)

Dim SubFolder As Object

For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(SubFolder)
    Call GetSubFolders(SubFolder)
Next SubFolder

End Sub

Sub ListFiles(ByRef Folder As Object)

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim cCount As Long
Dim lngColCount As Long

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

On Error Resume Next
For Each File In Folder.Files

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=File)
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(1)
'lngRowCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count
lngColCount = wsSource.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For cCount = 1 To lngColCount
        Range("A" & LastRow).Select
        ActiveCell = File.Name
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0), Address:=File.Path, TextToDisplay:=File.Path
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value = File.Worksheets(1).Range(1, lngColCount).Value
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value = File.Worksheets(1).Range(1, lngColCount).Format
    Next cCount
    
Next File

End Sub

Sub GetSubFolders(ByRef SubFolder As Object)

Dim FolderItem As Object
On Error Resume Next
For Each FolderItem In SubFolder.SubFolders
    Call ListFiles(FolderItem)
    Call GetSubFolders(FolderItem)
Next FolderItem

End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Again, I’d like to get all the cell values in row one (of each Excel file) and all the formats of each of these cells.

Comment: When you step through with `F8`, do you perhaps get stuck in a loop somewhere?

Comment: Comment out your On Error Resume Next - do you get errors?

Comment: (a) `File` isn't a `Workbook` object, so won't have a `Worksheets` property. That error is being masked by the `On Error Resume Next`.  You should only use that statement when you **know** what errors you are masking.  (b) Your code is updating values in the active sheet, which is in the workbook you opened - weren't you meant to be updating things in `sht`.  (c) Your code is "working" for me (i.e. it isn't locking up - I don't mean it does anything meaningful), but I worked with a directory that only had about 6 workbooks.  I suspect your "freeze" is just opening too many workbooks.

Comment: `Format` is not a range property - maybe you mean `NumberFormat` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's easier to manage the process if you get all of the matching files first, and then loop through them.

Lightly tested:

```
Sub GetFolder_Data_Collection()

    Dim colFiles As Collection, c As Range
    Dim strPath As String, f, sht As Worksheet
    Dim wbSrc As Workbook, wsSrc As Worksheet
    Dim rw As Range

    Set sht = ActiveSheet

    strPath = GetFolder

    Set colFiles = GetFileMatches(strPath, "*.xls*", True)

    With sht
        .Range("A:L").ClearContents
        .Range("A1").Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Name", "Path", "Cell", "Value", "Numberformat")
        Set rw = .Rows(2)
    End With

    For Each f In colFiles
        Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(f)
        Set wsSrc = wbSrc.Sheets(1)
        For Each c In wsSrc.Range(wsSrc.Range("a1"), _
                                  wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Cells

            sht.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rw.Cells(1), Address:=wbSrc.Path, TextToDisplay:=wbSrc.Name
            rw.Cells(2).Value = wbSrc.Path
            rw.Cells(3).Value = c.Address(False, False)
            rw.Cells(4).Value = c.Value
            rw.Cells(5).Value = c.NumberFormat
            Set rw = rw.Offset(1, 0)
        Next c
        wbSrc.Close False
    Next f
End Sub


'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetFileMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection

    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder

    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1

        For Each f In fldr.Files
            If UCase(f.Name) Like UCase(filePattern) Then colFiles.Add f
        Next f
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
    Loop
    Set GetFileMatches = colFiles
End Function

Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: "Lightly tested" LOL

Comment: OK - "run once on 4 files with a single subfolder, and no tricky merged cells etc etc."

Comment: I just ran it with about a dozen files in two levels of folders and it worked.  (But, again, no merged cells.)

Comment: OK - now "medium tested"...   ;-)

Comment: So, so, so nice Tim!!  Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It can do like this also.

```
Sub GetFileFromFolder()
    Dim n           As Long
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim colResult As Collection
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    Dim vSplit
    Dim strFn As String
    Dim vR() As String
    Dim p As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet, Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, rngDB As Range


    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        p = Application.PathSeparator
        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        With fd
            .Show
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
            .Title = "Select Folder"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
            Else
                strFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
                Set colResult = SearchFolder(strFolder)

                i = colResult.Count
                For k = 1 To i
                    If colResult(k) Like "*.xls*" Then
                        n = n + 1
                        ReDim Preserve vR(1 To 5, 1 To n)
                        Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(colResult(k))
                        Set Ws = Wb.Worksheets(1)

                        lngColCount = Ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count

                        vSplit = Split(colResult(k), p)
                        strFn = vSplit(UBound(vSplit))
                        vR(1, n) = strFn
                        vR(2, n) = Left(colResult(k), Len(colResult(k)) - Len(strFn))
                        vR(3, n) = colResult(k)
                        vR(4, n) = Ws.Cells(1, lngColCount).Value
                        vR(5, n) = Ws.Cells(1, lngColCount).NumberFormat
                        Wb.Close (0)
                    End If
                Next k
                With sht
                    .UsedRange.Clear
                    .Range("A1").Value = "Name"
                    .Range("B1").Value = "Path"
                    .Range("a2").Resize(n, 5) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
                    Set rngDB = .Range("c2").Resize(n)
                    For Each rng In rngDB
                        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rng, Address:=rng.Value
                    Next rng
                    .Columns.AutoFit
                End With
            End If
        End With
End Sub
Function SearchFolder(strRoot As String)
    Dim FS As Object
    Dim fsFD As Object
    Dim f As Object

    Dim colFile As Collection
    Dim p As String

    On Error Resume Next
    p = Application.PathSeparator
    If Right(strRoot, 1) = p Then
    Else
        strRoot = strRoot & p
    End If

    Set FS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set fsFD = FS.GetFolder(strRoot)
    Set colFile = New Collection
    For Each f In fsFD.Files
        colFile.Add f.Path
    Next f

    SearchSubfolder colFile, fsFD

    Set SearchFolder = colFile
    Set fsFD = Nothing
    Set FS = Nothing
    Set colFile = Nothing

End Function
Sub SearchSubfolder(colFile As Collection, objFolder As Object)
    Dim sbFolder As Object
    Dim f As Object
    For Each sbFolder In objFolder.subfolders
        SearchSubfolder colFile, sbFolder
        For Each f In sbFolder.Files
            colFile.Add f.Path
        Next f
    Next sbFolder

End Sub
```