# Select multiple folders - VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using macro to merge CSV files into one.
Macro is working good, but I have one block, that allows to select a folder with CSV files to merge.

Two questions:

1. Can I choose more than one folder to merge? (In one folder I have a lot of CSV files.).
2. How A can choose other initial directory from where to choose the folders? I need use folders from server.

Code block:

```
'Browse to the folder with CSV files
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFolder = oApp.BrowseForFolder(0, "Select folder with CSV files", 512)
If Not oFolder Is Nothing Then
    foldername = oFolder.Self.Path
    If Right(foldername, 1) <> "\" Then
        foldername = foldername & "\"
    End If
```

now my availability to choose one folder from:

[image: Not enough choice]

I would love to choose from more like this:

[image: More choice]

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154354/how-to-loop-through-all-subfolders-and-get-contents-of-row-1-of-each-excel-file/45156109#45156109) is for excell file. After change to like  "*.csv" , you can use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting *multiple folders* is not possible at all. Even selecting *two folders* at the same time will not work.

You can select …

- *multiple files* in *one* folder (see [@FunThomas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45302877/3219613))
- OR *one* folder only.

Here is how to select *one* folder:

```
Public Sub SelectFolder()
    Dim fdl As FileDialog

    Set fdl = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fdl
        .InitialFileName = "C:\Temp" 'where we start choosing a folder
        If .Show <> -1 Then
            MsgBox "canceled" 'nothing was selected
        Else
            Debug.Print .SelectedItems(1) 'the selected folder
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Application.FileDialog`. This allows to browse the folder and select files.

```
Dim fileCount As Long 

' Open the file dialog 
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen) 
    .AllowMultiSelect = True 
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv"
    .Show 

    For fileCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count 
        Debug.print .SelectedItems(fileCount) 
    Next fileCount  

End With
```

Comment: Yea thanks it's working. but now i have to mark in folder all csv files :) and still can take only one folder, not more

Comment: So you want to allow the user to select multiple files in multiple folders all at once? Don't think that this is possible

Comment: @SkirmanteValentaite selecting multiple folders is not possible at all. Even selecting two folders at the same time will not work. You can select *multiple files* in *one* folder OR *one* folder only.

Comment: can you help me to edit @FunThomas macro to select not multiple files bus one folder? I'm not good at macros writing I'am able just to combine one macro from separate blocks :)

Comment: @SkirmanteValentaite just us `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)` without filters and without `AllowMultiSelect`. Obviously you don't need the loop either because there is only one selected item `.SelectedItems(1)` when choosing folders. See my answer.