# Get sub-folders name with files name by VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to get *subfolders* name with files name through Excel VBA.
What I really want is `Column A` shows *subfolders name*, `Column B` shows *files name*.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Private xRow As Long

Sub Get_MAIN_File_Names()
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Dim xDirect As String
    Dim xRootFolder As Folder
    Dim DrawingNumb As String
    Dim RevNumb As String
    Dim rootFolderStr As String

    Set fso = New FileSystemObject
    xRow = 0
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .Title = "Select Main File"
       .Show

       'PROCESS ROOT FOLDER
       If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
          xDirect = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
          Set xRootFolder = fso.GetFolder(xDirect)
          ProcessFolder fso, xRootFolder
       End If

    End With

End Sub

Private Sub ProcessFolder(fso As FileSystemObject, xFolder As Folder)
    Dim xFiles As Files
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xSubFolders As Folders
    Dim xSubFolder As Folder
    Dim xSubFolderName As String
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileTime As String

    Set xFiles = xFolder.Files
    'Adding Column names
    Cells(1, "A").Value = "SubFolder Name"
    Cells(1, "B").Value = "File Name"
    Cells(1, "C").Value = "Modified Date/Time"

    For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
       xSubFolderName = xSubFolder.Name
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xSubFolderName
       xRow = xRow + 1
    Next xSubFolder

    'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
    For Each xFile In xFiles

      'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
       xFileName = xFile.Name
       xFileTime = xFile.DateLastModified

      'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = xFileName
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 2) = xFileTime
       xRow = xRow + 1
    Next xFile

    Set xSubFolders = xFolder.SubFolders
    For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
        ProcessFolder fso, xSubFolder
    Next xSubFolder

End Sub
```

However, I don't get what I want. I think the problem is here:

```
For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
   xSubFolderName = xSubFolder.Name
   ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xSubFolderName
   xRow = xRow + 1
Next xSubFolder
```

Which part do I ignore? Or is there another way to solve?
I think the code is too long. Maybe inefficient. How to modify the code?

Comment: I think if you delete the entire section that you think has a problem, and instead add in a line saying `ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xFolder.Name` into the section where you are writing out the other info, it will probably work.

Comment: refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45154354/how-to-loop-through-all-subfolders-and-get-contents-of-row-1-of-each-excel-file/45156109#45156109)

Comment: @YowE3K Great. It works. I think you can answer the question and I will mark it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your entire

```
For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
   xSubFolderName = xSubFolder.Name
   ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xSubFolderName
   xRow = xRow + 1
Next xSubFolder
```

section is going to fail because you haven't defined `xSubFolders` at that point.  Even if it didn't fail, it wouldn't do what you wanted because it would be moving the writing of the subfolder name away from the rows where you are writing the file details.

To resolve your issue you should delete that section and simply write the folder name out at the same time as you write the file details:

```
Private Sub ProcessFolder(fso As FileSystemObject, xFolder As Folder)
    Dim xFiles As Files
    Dim xFile As File
    Dim xSubFolders As Folders
    Dim xSubFolder As Folder
    Dim xFileName As String
    Dim xFileTime As String

    Set xFiles = xFolder.Files
    Set xSubFolders = xFolder.SubFolders
    'Adding Column names
    'This should really be done once in the main procedure, rather than being performed
    'for every folder processed, but is simply overwriting the information written
    'last time through so will be inefficient but not incorrect.
    Cells(1, "A").Value = "SubFolder Name"
    Cells(1, "B").Value = "File Name"
    Cells(1, "C").Value = "Modified Date/Time"

    'LOOPS THROUGH EACH FILE NAME IN FOLDER
    For Each xFile In xFiles

      'EXTRACT INFORMATION FROM FILE NAME
       xFileName = xFile.Name
       xFileTime = xFile.DateLastModified

      'INSERT INFO INTO EXCEL
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 0) = xFolder.Name
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 1) = xFileName
       ActiveCell.Offset(xRow, 2) = xFileTime
       xRow = xRow + 1
    Next xFile

    Set xSubFolders = xFolder.SubFolders
    For Each xSubFolder In xSubFolders
        ProcessFolder fso, xSubFolder
    Next xSubFolder

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this version.

```
Sub TestListFolders()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

     'create a new workbook for the folder list

     'commented out by dr
     'Workbooks.Add

     'line added by dr to clear old data
    Cells.Delete

     ' add headers
    With Range("A1")
        .Formula = "Folder contents:"
        .Font.Bold = True
        .Font.Size = 12
    End With

    Range("A3").Formula = "Folder Path:"
    Range("B3").Formula = "Folder Name:"
    Range("C3").Formula = "Size:"
    Range("D3").Formula = "Subfolders:"
    Range("E3").Formula = "Files:"
    Range("F3").Formula = "Short Name:"
    Range("G3").Formula = "Short Path:"
    Range("A3:G3").Font.Bold = True

     'ENTER START FOLDER HERE
     ' and include subfolders (true/false)
    ListFolders "C:\Users\Excel\Desktop\Coding\Microsoft Excel\Work Samples\Finance\", True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub ListFolders(SourceFolderName As String, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
     ' lists information about the folders in SourceFolder
     ' example: ListFolders "C:\", True
    Dim FSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Dim SourceFolder As Scripting.Folder, SubFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Dim r As Long

    Set FSO = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    Set SourceFolder = FSO.GetFolder(SourceFolderName)

     'line added by dr for repeated "Permission Denied" errors

    On Error Resume Next

     ' display folder properties
    r = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    Cells(r, 1).Formula = SourceFolder.Path
    Cells(r, 2).Formula = SourceFolder.Name
    Cells(r, 3).Formula = SourceFolder.Size
    Cells(r, 4).Formula = SourceFolder.SubFolders.Count
    Cells(r, 5).Formula = SourceFolder.Files.Count
    Cells(r, 6).Formula = SourceFolder.ShortName
    Cells(r, 7).Formula = SourceFolder.ShortPath
    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFolders SubFolder.Path, True
        Next SubFolder
        Set SubFolder = Nothing
    End If

    Columns("A:G").AutoFit

    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing

     'commented out by dr
     'ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

As an alternative, you can download the sample file from the link below (click 'Download Now').  That Macro will do a nice job for you.

http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2011/11/how-to-get-list-of-all-files-in-a-folder-and-sub-folders/

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided is unlikely to work for a number of reasons, have a look at the changes below, which might help:

```
Private Sub ProcessFolder(FSO as FileSystemObject, xFolder As Folder)
    Dim xFile as File
    Dim CurRow As Integer

    'Your original code was going to wipe over the data when you got to each new SubFolder. This should prevent that:
    For CurRow = 1 to 100000
        If Range("A" & CurRow).Value = "" And Range("B" & CurRow).Value = "" Then Exit For
    Next CurRow
    If CurRow = 1 then
            Range("A1").Value = "Sub Folder Name"
            Range("B1").Value = "File Name"
            Range("C1").Value = "Modified Date/Time"
            CurRow = CurRow + 1
    End If

    Range("A" & CurRow).Value = xFolder.Name
    CurRow = CurRow + 1

    For Each xFile in xFolder.Files
        Range("B" & CurRow).Value = xFile.Name
        Range("C" & CurRow).Value = xFile.DateLastModified
        CurRow = CurRow + 1
    Next xFile
End Sub
```

Comment: "Your original code was going to wipe over the data when you got to each new SubFolder." - Actually, it wouldn't - they always wrote to row `xRow` (a module-scope variable) and incremented that by 1 after each write.  There **is** an issue in that they initialise `xRow` to `0` in `Get_MAIN_File_Names` when it should be initialised to `2`, but that's an issue irrespective of how many subfolders are processed.  (Once they get it fixed to work for the first folder, all the other folders would be correctly written below it.)

Comment: @YowE3K apologies, I missed the xRow definition. I would still adjust the other parts of your code though, as there is no need to store the data as a separate variable unless you require it later. The only exception to this is for speed of processing, in which case, you could build an array of all the data and then write it all in one hit at the end (probably negligible gains for the numbers of files you want to process).

Comment: Yeah, I agree that `xFileName = xFile.Name` is fairly pointless which is why I just added the line to write `xFolder.Name`, rather than put it into a temporary variable.  (I guess there could be some efficiency gains to put the folder name into a temporary variable so that the `.Name` property was only accessed once rather than for each file within the folder - but there's definitely no advantage to storing `xFile.Name` and `DateLastModified`.) But I didn't want to change the OP's code too much, especially as they already had the answer from the comment so probably would never see it. :D

Comment: @YowE3K fair enough.

Comment: Thank to both of you. If there are any efficient code to solve, could you please add to question for reference? I think it is important to learn optimized solution. Appreciate again

Comment: @PeterChen Unless you have thousands of files, or you are running the code many, many times each day, any improvement to the current solution probably wouldn't be worth the effort of rewriting it.  And requests for "optimised solutions" for working code should be made on Code Review rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: Oh. Honestly I had never heard of `Code Review`. And I actually have thousands of files... Thank you for comment